# Абсолютное удаление объекта с окна sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Вопрос звучит просто, но Я нигде не смог найти ответ на этот вопрос. Как полностью удалить отрисованый объект из окна в sfml. Скажу сразу, что вариант "сделать невидимым или переместить его на огромные координаты" не подойдёт.

Comment: Что такое «объект»? Где и как вы его нарисовали?

Comment: Никогда не пользовался SFML, но просто глянув на пример понятно, что он перерисовывает элементы: `window.clear(); window.display();`. Просто очиситие и перерисуйте заново. У вас должен быть контейнер элементов видимо (`sf::Drawable`).

Answer (score 1):

Окно в SFML отрисовывает те элементы, которые вы в него добавили с помощью `window.draw()`. При помощи `window.clear();` окно очищает очередь на отрисовку - удаляет все объекты из окна (из очереди). Если объект больше не нужен, просто не добавляйте его на отрисовку.
Основной цикл для SFML выглядит примерно так:

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
   // обработка событий окна

    
    window.clear(); // очистка очереди на отрисовку - удаляет из окна все элементы

    window.draw(object); // добавление объектов в очередь на отрисовку

    window.display(); // отображение окна
}
```

Когда объектов в окне много, обычно держат свой массив указателей на объекты, которые нужно отрисовать - `std::vector<sf::Drawable*> my_draw_objects;`. И в цикле добавляют в окно. Удалив указатель на элемент из своего массива, он не попадет на отрисовку в окно.

```
std::vector<sf::Drawable*> my_draw_objects;

{
    window.clear(); // очистка очереди на отрисовку

    for(auto object : my_draw_objects)
        window.draw(object); // добавление объектов в очередь на отрисовку

    window.display(); // отображение окна
}
```

Comment: Как же мне убрать объект из win.draw()? Я вроде бы не умею изменять код в процессе его работы

Comment: @DmitryK, по моему `window.draw()` именно рисует, а `window.display()` делает swap buffers

Comment: Изменять код в процессе его работы конечно же нельзя. Но написание выполнения кода по условию - начало любого учебника по языкам программирования. `if(условие) win.draw(объект);`. Вы не удаляете объект из окна - вы просто на очередной итерации цикла не рисуете его в окне. Результат - объект удален из окна. А если у вас вектор указателей объектов на рисование, то удалив указатель на ненужный объект из вектора, он опять-таки не нарисуется в окне.

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Вы правы. Я попытался упростить `логическую` модель процесса отрисовки окна для новичка. Мне показалось, что объяснить принцип работы двойной буфферизации в видеокартах человеку не понимающему как рисовать или не рисовать объект будет слишком сложно.